# Currency Exchange isn't working in Android

Tags: android

I have run into an obstacle when doing my Android application. My issue is that I cannot create an onTabListener for my tabs. I have three tabs with different names. The problem is that they all have the same tab count. In my code I ran this:

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        int n = getActionBar().getTabCount();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

This makes a toast saying the value of the tab (for example: 0, 1, 2, 3), but all of the tabs have the same indicator. I cannot make an onTabListener if I have all my tabs have the same indicator. Here is my full code:

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        int n = getActionBar().getTabCount();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // hide the given tab
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // probably ignore this event
    }
};

// Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    actionBar.addTab(
            actionBar.newTab()
                    .setText(tabTitle[i])
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));
}
```

What is the issue? Is there any way I can create an onTabListener using the tab's title? Any help to this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by same indicator?

Comment: I mean the tab count.

Comment: all you are going is getting how many tabs you created....which tells you nothing really

Comment: Then please tell me what I should do.

Answer (score 0):

all you are doing is getting the number of tabs you have...

you need to do `tab.getPosition()` to get what one selected

```
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    int n = tab.getPosition();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have selected: " + n, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the tabcount is the same for all the tabs (all of them are 3)

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is?? If all you want to know is what tab you selected then getting the position of the tab will tell you that. getting the count tells you nothing but how many tabs you have